# Write NodeJS stream into a string synchronously

Tags: node.js, express

I know that one can synchronously read a file in NodeJS like this:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var content = fs.readFileSync('myfilename');
console.log(content);
```

I am instead interested in being able to read the contents from a stream into a string synchronously. Thoughts?

Comment: You can't, and you shouldn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Streams in node.js are not synchronous - they are event driven.  They just aren't synchronous.  So, you can't get their results into a string synchronously.

If you have no choice but to use a stream, then you have no choice but to deal with the contents of the stream asynchronously.

If you can change the source of the data to a synchronous source such as the `fs.readFileSync()` that you show, then you can do that (though generally not recommended for a multi-user server process).